# Отображение текста по строкам при создании метки в конструкторе карт

Tags: яндекс-карты

При создании метки в конструкторе карт тект при вводе отображается по строкам.
Адрес
Телефон
E-mail
Сайт
[image: отображение текста при создании метки]

А отображении данного текста у пользователя (когда я ему скидываю ссылку на карту) происходит сплошным текстом: Адрес Телефон E-mail Сайт
[image: отображение текста у пользователя]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать, чтобы текст у пользователя отображался построчно.

Answer (score 0):

Поле "Описание" меток и других пользовательских объектов в Конструкторе поддерживает html-разметку. Для переноса строк в простейшем случае используется тэг `<br>`:

```
ООО "Магазин"<br>
Телефон: 223-322-22-33<br>
Адрес: Москва, ул.Ленина, д.10
```

Все остальные методы форматирования (абзацы, блоки, CSS-стили и др.) вы найдёте в любой доступной документации по HTML.

Comment: "YaCor'" Спасибо за ответ.